# Dialog box is not fit for the screen on multiple selecting files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, ember-1

I'm having dialog box with the upload files for the folder, when I'm selecting the multiple files (more than 25 files approx) for the upload, the dialog box getting increased the length to the bottom and scroll bar is not showing to scroll down to see the files fully.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here I have added 36 files and when I want to see the uploaded file list its not showing fully and scroll bar also showing to scroll down to see the further.

Html for the dialog box is here:

```
<div class="upload-files-dialog" tabindex="0" role="dialog" style="position: absolute; height: auto; top: 0px; left: 277px; display: block; width: 270px; right: auto; bottom: auto;" aria-describedby="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4">
```

Corresponding css style I have tried as:

```
div.upload-files-dialog {
 {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 226px;
    display: block;
    width: 270px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
 }
```

I have mentioned height as auto, then also its not getting adjust with the screen.

The corresponding hbr file for the dialog is here:

```
{{#if view.showFileList}}
    {{file-list view.fileList}}
{{/if}}
```

The **fileList** of corresponding ember code is here:

```
        menuContext: null,

        formData: function () {
            if (!this.get('menuContext.formData')) {
                this.set('menuContext.formData', Ember.Object.create({ data: Ember.Object.create({ }), files: [] }));
            }
            return this.get('menuContext.formData.data');
        }.property('menuContext'),

        uploadHandle: null,

        showFileList: function () {
            return (this.get('uploadHandle.files.length') || this.get('menuContext.formData.data.file.length')) > 1;
       }.property('uploadHandle.files.length', 'menuContext.formData.data.file'),

        fileList: function () {
            return this.get('uploadHandle.files') || [].slice.call(this.get('menuContext.formData.data.file'));
        }.property('uploadHandle.files', 'menuContext.formData.data.file')
```

When I'm pressing the console (F12), the scroll bar is getting coming and dialog box is also changed as fit for the page. But I need on when I'm upload the file time itself. I don't know where it is getting the problem either css or ember or jquery. Can anyone please suggest me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `max-height` for the `div.upload-files-dialog` to make the overflow to occur.

Example:

```
div.upload-files-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 370px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 226px;
    display: block;
    width: 270px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Allan. Its not working, when I'm giving max-height, the upload file list are showing as blur in background and scroll bar also not visible

Comment: Hi @ScottDon . Is it working now? I'm asking since you've marked my answer right.

Comment: Yes, Allan, Its working and also I added `overflow: scroll`.